# Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\next-app\app\register\error.js

Tags: next.js

i am using nextjs 13.4, have a directory /register in app router. beside the page.js file i have added error.js to catch the error, the error file didnt worked so i removed it. now the app giving the error "Module not found cant resolve error.js". although i didnt add any reference to the page.js. before adding error.js file it was all good. kindly help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJqap.jpg)